# Adding a lot of texts

Tags: three.js

I use threeJS to draw a 2d scene.
But when I add a lot of texts into the scene by creating canvas and using texture, browser is get it crashes!

So how can I add a lot of text into the scene?

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/) will help you.

Comment: I had noticed this, but I didn't find any demos